# Records (logs) in nginx, blank are created but not updated

Tags: nginx, log-files

I am getting the locomotive, I have stopped working the logs, I have created them again, I have the subdomains with the logs turned on, I checked the configuration up and down nginx and it does not work, only a registry works that created a post error.log in /var/log/nginx and that is updated when you start nginx, the rest of logs are created as I have them configured in site-avalible, but they are blank

An example of the created logs:

> -rw-r----- 1 www-data adm 0 May 26 10:42 blog_access.log
>
> -rw-r----- 1 www-data adm 0 May 26 10:42 blog_error.log

This is the only one that works:

> -rw-r----- 1 www-data adm 14591 May 26 12:40 error.log

It compiles when nginx is installed:

> --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
>
> --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log

I do not understand why taking the rest of logs with the same permissions and owners that error.log does not work?

Comment: Have you tried remove log files and restart nginx?

Comment: I had moved the old logs to another location and mysteriously continue to update, even if they are no longer in the path specified in the subdomain configuration file.

This is a ghost thing!

Comment: If you don't restart/reload nginx after moving log files, nginx will still use the old file handle of the log file. When you move a file to another directory, only the directory entries are changed, not the actual file handle. Therefore nginx keeps writing to the same file, which is simply in different location.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes, but I service nginx restart when I make some changes, now delete all the logs, but the new ones that are generated, are empty.

Comment: Please show your complete nginx configuration in the question.

Comment: In the end I reboot the server and it worked, I suppose the nginx process was left hanging.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the server was solved